# Help needed to understand statements about torus

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, lie-groups, complex-geometry, proof-explanation

I am having trouble understanding two statements:

> Let $A$ be an algebraic curve in $\mathbb{P}^2$ over $\mathbb{C}.$ Consider its normalization $$\pi: \hat{A} \to A.$$ If genus $g(\hat{A})=1,$ then $\hat{A}$ is a topologically a torus .

I understand up to here, as it follows from Riemann-Roch theorem. What I don't understand are the following statements:

> It's (i.e. torus's) group of holomorphic automorphisms $Aut(\hat{A})$ is a complex Lie group whose connected component at the identity is a complex torus $T$ which acts freely and transitively on $\hat{A}$.
>
> The quotient $\Gamma:= Aut(\hat{A})/T$ is a finite group of order at most six.

I don't understand either of these points. Could someone clarify? Which theorems are being used here? Please let me know of references, if possible, for the proof.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\hat{A}$ is isomorphic (complex analytically) to a torus of the form $\mathbb{C}/\Lambda$, where $\Lambda=\langle 1,\tau\rangle$ is a discrete subgroup of rank 2 in $\mathbb{C}$ (that is, a lattice) and $\tau\in\mathbb{H}$. It is a well-known theorem that any holomorphic map between tori is the composition of a group homomorphism with a translation.

We see that translations are automorphisms of $\hat{A}$, and so $\hat{A}\leq\mbox{Aut}(\hat{A})$ (since if $t_x$ is translation by $x$, $t_x\circ t_y=t_{x+y}$). What's left is to look at the elements $G$ of the automorphism group that fix 0. An automorphism that fixes 0 is given by a complex number $\lambda$ such that $\lambda\Lambda=\Lambda$. It is not hard to show that this implies that $\lambda$ is either a fourth root or a sixth root of unity. After analyzing different cases, we get that $G$ can be either $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ (given by the involution $x\mapsto -x$, all tori have this), $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ (in this case the torus is isomorphic to the torus $\mathbb{C}/\langle1, i\rangle$) or $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$ (and here the torus is isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}/\langle1,e^{2\pi i/6}\rangle$).

Putting all this together, we get that the automorphism group is isomorphic to $G\ltimes\hat{A}$, where $G$ has order 2 (this is true for the general torus), 4 or 6.

**Edit:** A good beginning reference for this is Miranda's book on Algebraic curves and Riemann surfaces.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But I don't quite get how this answers my question. I specifically want to understand the two statements in my question. And I cannot find a discussion related to my question in Miranda's text? Could you perhaps give me the precise chapter that treats above?

Comment: This answers your question by showing that the automorphism group is $G\ltimes\hat{A}$, and the connected component that contains the identity is $\{0\}\times\hat{A}\simeq\hat{A}$. The quotient of this group by $\hat{A}$ is isomorphic to $G$, which is of order either $2$, $4$ or $6$. I don't have Miranda's book on me right now, but look up the part where he talks about automorphisms of complex tori.

Comment: Could you explain more (in the first line of 2nd paragraph) about why it follows that $\hat{A}\leq Aut(\hat{A})$ from what you wrote before?

Comment: Well if $t_x:\hat{A}\to\hat{A}$ denotes translation by $x$ (that is, $t_x(a)=a+x$), then we obtain an injective homomorphism $\hat{A}\to\mbox{Aut}(\hat{A})$ where $x\mapsto t_x$.

Comment: Oh yes. (I should have seen that.) Thanks!

Comment: Hi, is it immediate that $Aut(C)$ is isomorphic to $G \ltimes \hat{A}$? I can't see this.

Comment: Well, the automorphisms are either invertible homomorphisms or the composition of a homomorphism with a translation. This shows that any automorphism is the "product" (that is, composition) of an element of $G$ with an element of $\hat{A}$. Moreover, if $g\in G$ and $t_x\in\hat{A}$, then $gt_xg^{-1}=t_{g(x)}$, and so $\hat{A}$ is normal in $\mbox{Aut}(\hat{A})$. Moreover, $t_x g t_x^{-1}=t_xgt_{-x}=t_{x-g(x)}g$, and this gives the relation we need for the semi-direct product.